# change permission sets from visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, profile

I am looking to change permission sets from visualforce UI and not through Setup.

Any ideas of how to achieve this.?

Comment: Sorry, the question was not clear enough to understand the requirement however I think you want to change permissions from a UI in VF not from setup?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to assign permission sets to users from Custom UI.

Comment: have you checked out the permissionSetAssginement object (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm) ? This object will allow you to assign  the permission set for a user. This is basically a junction between the user and the permission set.

Comment: From what I see from the document above, it supports only `create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()`. There are no `update()`

Comment: Since there are no metadata call supporting update, I do not think that the requirement can be implemented by any other method as well.

Comment: When you want to change the permission set, you will have to delete the current assignment and create a new one. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score -2):

Is this you looking for,
IN VF page you can get input  Permission Set and whom to assign.
Through Apex,

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> newPSAssignments = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
 newPSAssignments.add(new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId=Assignee,PermissionSetId=PermissionSetID  ));        
  upsert newPSAssignments;
```